# cat ~/foo and code ~/foo direct me to different files

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin

I just set up a new computer with VSCode and Cygwin. I have cygwin set up as my VSCode integrated terminal with:

```
{
    // start bash, not the mintty, or you'll get a new window
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
    // Use this to keep bash from doing a 'cd ${HOME}'
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
      "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
    },
    // Make it a login shell
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
      "-l"
    ],
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
  }
```

I've noticed a funny thing when I use `~/`-prefixed paths in my commands.

Most of the time, `~` refers to $HOME, which, for me, is `/home/mason`. Packages installed by cygwin all translate that path to `C:\cygwin64\home\mason` on the host NTFS filesystem (this is the default setup for cygwin).

However, specifically with `code` - the command-line executable that launches vscode - any path starting with `~` takes me to some subfolder of `C:\home\mason`.

For example:

`code ~` opens a new VSCode editor window that's rooted at `C:\home\mason`, whereas I need it to refer to `C:\cygwin64\home\mason`.

Similarly, I suspect this same failure-to-translate is the root cause of hg failing to use `code --wait` as my graphical editor. `$TMP` is `/tmp`; cygwin-packaged binaries (like hg) understand that this translates on-filesystem to `C:\cygwin64\tmp`, whereas `code` apparently thinks that `/tmp` means `C:\tmp`, so it saves the tmp file to a different place than where hg is looking for it.

Any ideas where things are going wrong between Cygwin and VSC? I don't even know who is wrong here. I think the `code` binary seen by cygwin is probably meant to work for WSL and it's accidentally sort-of working for cygwin but it doesn't have the "translate to cygwin FUSE" part packaged in.

```
$ which code
/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

```
$ env | sort
_=/usr/bin/env
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
AMDRMPATH=C:\Program Files\AMD\RyzenMaster\
APPDATA=C:\Users\mason\AppData\Roaming
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME=\\.\pipe\crashpad_8904_FNXAORTRNUFRROHO
COLORTERM=truecolor
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=MASON-THREADRIP
COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DokanLibrary1_LibraryPath_x64=C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.4.1\lib\
DokanLibrary1_LibraryPath_x86=C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.4.1\x86\lib\
DokanLibrary1=C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.4.1\
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
EXECIGNORE=*.dll
HOME=/home/mason
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\mason
HOSTNAME=mason-threadripper
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\mason\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\MASON-THREADRIP
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=32
OLDPWD=/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/dev
OneDrive=C:\Users\mason\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\mason\OneDrive
ORIGINAL_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=undefined
OS=Windows_NT
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/.cargo/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PRINTER=Brother MFC-L2740DW series Printer
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=23
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0802
PROFILEREAD=true
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
PWD=/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/dev/tilequest
SESSIONNAME=Console
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows
TEMP=/tmp
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=1.57.1
TERM_PROGRAM=vscode
TERM=xterm-256color
TMP=/tmp
TZ=America/Los_Angeles
USER=mason
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=MASON-THREADRIP
USERDOMAIN=MASON-THREADRIP
USERNAME=mason
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\mason
WINDIR=C:\Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this open, because there might be a better/less brittle way to solve this issue for non-cygwin "posix-like" binaries, but I hacked around my immediate problem by writing a wrapper script to munge filenames specifically for vscode.

I have this saved in my $PATH at `$HOME/bin/code` (which is a default location that cygwin's .bashrc checks for).

```
heads=( "${@:1:$(($# - 1))}" )
tail=${@:${#@}} 
"/cygdrive/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code" ${heads[@]} $(sed -e 's/^[/]/\/cygwin64\//' <<< $tail)
```

This script passes through all commandline args to the real `code` except the last one, which it rewrites with `/cygwin64` in the front. This did indeed fix `code --wait` for use as my $EDITOR and it also just makes `code` start making sense in general for cygwin.